# Input 0 of layer gru is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using TF 2.5 and I'm punctually following the tutorial on https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation just to get some confidence.

But I don't understand why after building the model I get an inconsistency on the dimension; it expects a 3-dimensional layer and it receives only two.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer gru is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (64, 100)
```

Meanwhile this problem is not found in the tutorial, even using their own dataset, and this leaves me puzzled.

I then tried various combinations, even generating a dummy dimension in the dataset, but I don't get the desired result.

I somehow understand that the problem should lies in the dataset conformation since:

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((64, 100), (64, 100)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>
```

I see I am missing a dimension. But how can I "add" a dimension to it, or viceversa exclude the model to expect 3 dimension (but, in that case, I am wondering what's the meaning of the whole model), it's not clear.

I have read many similar cases (both with GRU and LSTM) and tried various options, but given my unfamiliarity, I feel I am at a standstill.

I would be grateful if someone could give me a tip.

Here is my code (that replicates the one on TensorFlow page linked above):

(this is also my very first post on SO!)

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000

dataset = (dataset
           .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
           .batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
           .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

vocab_size = len(vocab)
embedding_dim = 256
rnn_units = 1024


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
        
    def call(self, inputs, states=None, return_state=False, training=False):
        x = inputs
        x = self.embedding(x, training=training)
        if states is None:
            states = self.gru.get_initial_state(x)
        x = self.dense(x, training=training)
        
        if return_state:
            return x, states
        else:
            return x

model = MyModel(vocab_size=len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary()), embedding_dim=embedding_dim, rnn_units=rnn_units)

for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1):
    example_batch_predictions = model(input_example_batch)
    print (example_batch_predictions.shape, "# (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)")
```

Comment: You say `self.embedding = GRU(...)` probably a typo while following the tutorial. Embedding + GRU should be fine with that shapes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found the issue thanks to your comment, was in fact a line missing!